# How to improve OpenCV background drop from two images

Tags: javascript, node.js, opencv

I am using OpenCV with NodeJS (opencv4nodejs) and am attempting to replace background from webcam pics (one with and one without head in the frame).

My code works but the quality of the mask is useless presumably because I need to apply better filters but I am not sure what.

Here's my simple code

```
const bgSubtractor = new cv.BackgroundSubtractorMOG2()

const back = cv.imread('/app/src/services/back.jpg').bgrToGray()
const face = cv.imread('/app/src/services/face.jpg').bgrToGray()

bgSubtractor.apply(back)
return bgSubtractor.apply(face)
```

I've gray scaled them but that's about it. I'm not attaching particular images as I want to see if I can make a generic model but the intention is to replace the background from someone taking a headshot with their cam then asked to drop out for the background (which could vary) shot. I am not sure it's possible to obtain a decent quality with just two images though.

Perhaps a different would be better? I assume that if I could properly align the images to account for minor shifts between stills and subtract but perhaps that's what the cv.BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 does? I've worked from a few examples that use movies but the results didn't pan out well.

Comment: The MOG2 Background subtractor requires to be **learned**.  This means that you have to feed it several background images to it before it can properly extract out foreground from background.  Feed it some background images from your webcam first so it can learn the background, then feed it your face.

Comment: Related, but unfortunately in Python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26344036/python-opencv-background-subtraction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @rayryeng pointed out, MOG2 Bg Subtractor needs to be trained with several background samples in order to be able to understand what a background actually is.

Try in this way:

1. take several background images (pretty obvious :) )
2. feed with them the MOG object with a
   learning rate > 0
3. apply trained MOG to your frame with learning rate
   = 0 to retrieve foreground objects

[Very useful link that explains everything](https://answers.opencv.org/question/66084/using-backgroundsubtractormog2-for-images/)